# Why I click the row in table it show nothing in the next page?

Tags: php

The code is not function. It should go to the page that contain detail, but the detail show nothing. What is actually happen?

[image]

```
  function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $("#employee-click"); //document.getElementById("employee- 
  click");
   tbody.each(function() {
   $(this).on('click', function() {

   window.location.href = "detail.php";

   })
   })
    }
```

Comment: I assume you should be giving the page some parameters, which you’re not doing. Also I assume you want to add the handler to each row whereas here you’re adding one handler to the one element which has id employee-click

Answer (score 0):

I think you much set "employee-click" is class. Because if "employee-click" is id, it handler only 1 element

```
 function addRowHandlers() {
  var tbody = $(".employee-click"); 
   tbody.each(function() {
   $(this).on('click', function() {

   window.location.href = "detail.php";

   })
   })
    }
```